# Storing inputs in a list with a pic chip (picaxe programming)

Tags: list, variables, storing-data, picaxe

Never used picaxe before and am wondering how to or whether I can store a list of input values in a list to execute at the press of a 'go' button.

It is for a Programmable electrical vehicle I am making and am running out of time!

Any lines of code that I can use and adapt would be of great help!

Comment: By 'a list of input values' do you mean a list of values that you know at the time you write the program, or do you mean the PICAXE has to receive some data at run time and store it before taking some action based on the data?

Comment: I mean that the 18 pin pic chip has to receive data once it is in the unit and running - once the user has pressed a series of buttons in any random order, the unit will (hopefully) reproduce these actions live. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of the 'Variables' section of [part 2 of the PICAXE manual](http://www.picaxe.com/docs/picaxe_manual2.pdf).

On any PICAXE chip you can use the `POKE` and `PEEK` commands to store and retrieve a byte at a time from a specified memory location. You will need to check which range of addresses are available to use on the particular PICAXE chip you're using and you'll need to use a variable as a pointer to keep track of which location you're writing to or reading from, for example:

```
SYMBOL write_pointer = w0
SYMBOL read_pointer = w1
SYMBOL first_address = $1C ' lowest address available     
SYMBOL last_address = $1FF ' highest address available 
' (addresses here are for 18M2+, 14M2, 20M2, different for other PICAXE chips)

' Example of storing data:
write_pointer = first_address
DO
    ' Code goes here that produces the data to be stored - e.g. in variable b4
    POKE write_pointer, b4
    ' your code needs to determine when it's finished storing data, 
    ' shown here by 'something'
    IF something OR write_pointer = last_address THEN EXIT
    INC write_pointer
LOOP 

' Example of retrieving data again in the same order
FOR read_pointer = first_address TO write_pointer
    PEEK read_pointer, b4
    ' do something with the value that was retrieved
NEXT read_pointer
```

Depending on which PICAXE chip you have you could alternatively use scratchpad memory with `@ptr`, `@ptrinc` and `@ptrdec`, or indirect addressing of variables with `@bptr`, `@bptrinc` and `@bptrdec` - these would make your code simpler but aren't available on all chips. It's all explained in the manual.

If you're new to PICAXE make sure you understand the relationship between byte and word variables. In the example above I've used word variables `w0` and `w1` which means you can't use byte variables `b0` to `b3` at the same time.